# Using the DCT to show that a function of a complex variable defined by an integral is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that the function $$f(z) \equiv   \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+ix)^{z} (e^{\pi x}+1)}$$ is an entire function by using the dominated convergence theorem to argue that we can differentiate under the integral sign for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I basically need to show that the absolute value of the derivative of the integrand is dominated by a function that is integrable on $[0, \infty)$.

$$ \begin{align} \left|\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \frac{1}{(1+ix)^{z} (e^{\pi x}+1)}  \right| &= \frac{1}{e^{\pi x}+1}\left|\frac{\log(1+ix)}{(1+ix)^{z}} \right| \\ &= \frac{1}{e^{\pi x}+1}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \log^{2}(1+x^{2}) + \arctan^{2}(x)}}{(1+x^{2})^{\Re(z)/2}\left|(1+ix)^{i \, \Im(z)} \right|} \\  &=\frac{1}{e^{\pi x}+1}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \log^{2}(1+x^{2}) + \arctan^{2}(x)}}{(1+x^{2})^{\Re(z)/2}} \, e^{\Im(z) \arctan (x)} \tag{1} \end{align}$$

To show that $(1)$ is dominated by an integrable function on $[0, \infty)$, could I arbitrarily assume that $\left| \Re(z) \right| < \alpha$ and $\left| \Im (z) \right|< \beta$ and say that $(1)$ is dominated by

$$ \frac{1}{e^{\pi x}+1}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \log^{2}(1+x^{2}) + \arctan^{2}(x)}}{(1+x^{2})^{-\left| \alpha \right|/2}} \, e^{\left|\beta \right|\arctan (x)} ?$$

Comment: all you need is showing that $f'(z)$ exists for every $z$ : $\int_0^\infty (1+ix)^z \log(1+ix) \frac{1}{1+e^{\pi x}} dx = \int_0^\infty (\frac{d}{dz}(1+ix)^z) \frac{1}{1+e^{\pi x}} dx  =  \frac{d}{dz}\int_0^\infty (1+ix)^z \frac{1}{1+e^{\pi x}} dx = f'(z)$ where for exchanging $\frac{d}{dz}$ and $\int$ you can do as you want, write the limit explicitly, or use the absolute/uniform convergence or the dominated convergence as you wish.

Comment: Remember that differentiation is a local phenomenon. Therefore showing that exchanging derivative and integral need only be done on some neighborhood of any particular $z$. Thus you are correct that you can assume that $z$ is bounded. Provided the approach works for all bounds, it's good.